# Halt in Before filter still proceeds to After filter

Tags: ruby, sinatra

So my understanding is that the halt command should stop the request in the current filter, but it appears to continue on. What follows is a very simple Sinatra app demonstrating this.

server.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

before do
  puts "before halt"
  halt 401
  puts "after halt"
end

before '/partners*' do
  puts "i am in before /partners"
end

after '/partners*' do
  puts "i am in after /partners"
end

get '/partners/v1/:public_id' do
  puts "i am in the actual route"
end
```

I am calling 'get' on the following location: `localhost:4567/partners/v1/111`
What I expect to output:

```
before halt
```

What is actually outputting:

```
before halt
i am in after /partners
```

So my question's are exactly:
1. Why does the halt continue on at all (shown with it reaching `after '/partners*'`)
2. Why does it hit the `after '/partners*'` but not the `before '/partners*'`

Comment: my guess is you can't "halt" in a before clause, maybe ask the sinatra devs about it, maybe it's unexpected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the code for `halt`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L914) and [here is the code for `invoke`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1055), and just below `invoke` is [the method declaration for `dispatch!`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1055)

As you can see, `dispatch!` calls `invoke`, which runs the route block with support for `halt`ing. It also runs the `:before` filter in the `invoke` block.

```
invoke do
  static! if settings.static? && (request.get? || request.head?)
  filter! :before
  route!
```

So you can `halt` inside a `before` filter and it won't reach the route, which is why you don't see any output from your route block.

However, the `dispatch!` method also has an `ensure`:

```
ensure
  begin
    filter! :after unless env['sinatra.static_file']
```

An `ensure` does what it says, *it will always be evaluated*. This is why the `after '/partners*'` block is processed. This is expected behaviour (as it's coded quite clearly that way). Basically, if you put in an `after` block, it will get processed, regardless of `halt`s in `before` filters or route blocks.

From the docs:

> Routes are matched in the order they are defined. The first route that matches the request is invoked.

[and](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters)

> …filters are evaluated before each request within the same context as the routes

Now, the docs aren't explicit about this, but if you add the two quotes together I'd take that to mean "Filters are matched in the order they are defined." Basically, because it fits the actual behaviour.

All the `before` filters should run, but you put a `halt` in the first one, so the second one (`before '/partners*'`) doesn't run.

Comment: Interesting, this then means I shouldn't do anything in after filters that have dependencies on before filters. A little bit unintuitive in my mind but your right the docs do lay it out clearly. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerA Yes, I think you're right. If you keep in mind that `throw`/`catch` stops all processing and that `halt` is a loose synonym for that, and that an `after` filter is a loose synonym for `ensure` then you'll have it right. Glad I could help.